# convert dateTime to salesforce required dateTime format in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

For the dateTime `"2022-11-29T19:12:21Z"` getting INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD error from salesforce. So need to convert it in correct format that Salesforce accept.

Input: `"2022-11-29T19:12:21Z"`

Expected output: `2022-11-29T19:12:21.000+0000`

I tried this script:

```
{
     "lastDateTime": "2022-11-29T19:12:21Z" as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"}
}
```

Please help to get the expected output format.

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime must have a timezone so you can not just parse the input string into it directly. The input also misses milliseconds so it can not be parsed with the milliseconds format `.SSS`.

You can convert to a LocalDateTime first, then add a timezone (+0:00), then format to string with milliseconds and timezone. A DateTime must have a timezone so you can not just parse the input

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "lastDateTime": ("2022-11-29T19:12:21Z" as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"}  ++ |+00:00|) as String {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"}
}
```